# Identifying SQLException due to network problem

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring, sqlexception

I am developing a web application which uses 3 different databases(Oracle & MSSQL). This application contains spring and hibernate frameworks. In this application if databases goes down or some network issue comes I have to handle differently(While trying to access database). Currently if the above scenario comes  I am getting SQLException as the least cause. How do I identify that SQLException thrown is because of network issue or some query/data issue?

Answer (score 1):

Check the drivers' individual documentation and see what error codes are thrown as a result of the errors you described

**UPDATE**

```
} catch (SQLException se) {
   int count = 1;
   while (se != null) {
       System.out.println("SQLException " + count);
       System.out.println("Code: " + se.getErrorCode());
       System.out.println("SqlState: " + se.getSQLState());
       System.out.println("Error Message: " + se.getMessage());

       se = se.getNextException();
       count++;
   }
}
```

each database vendor provides their own error codes and states, if you check them you should be safe.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you'll just have to extract this information from the exception message.
For example in case of Oracle a SQLException exception with following message is thrown:

```
Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes I am getting closed connection as a error message. Is this reliable to depend on the message?

Comment: Not really. A vendor can change the behavior. It can be pretty reliable until you change used driver version, but it's more of a hack than a solid solution. If you need to detect the problem from your code and not just tell a user about it you should consider using error codes instead (though error codes may differ for different vendors).

Comment: Yes. I just don't want to show the message. From the code I should come to know about the real cause. I am little confused that which error code I have to check!!! I googled. Not much of help :-)

Comment: I googled this: [oracle jdbc error codes](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/java.920/a96654/ermesap.htm). You should also see [SQLException.getErrorCode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getErrorCode()). And I think [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-client.html) are MySQL error codes (not really sure since I don't use it).